# get sum of values passed to a lablel with in a session

Tags: .net

I have a . net application where a user enters a value in a text box and hit a button. Each time the user enters a new value in the text box and hits the button the new value entered should be summed to the previous entered value and so on (Initially at the start of the session the value should be set to 0).
I tried storing the value in a session variable, but when i hit the button the page re-lodes and forgets the old value. 
Could any one tell me how I could store a value globally in a session and use the value to add to the newly entered value.

Comment: WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming an ASP.NET page that resets to 0 when you first hit the page you might want something like:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    Session["sessionVar"] = 0;
}
else
{
    Session["sessionVar"] = ((int)Session["sessionVar"]) + newValue;
}
```

However, If that is what you want I wouldn't recommend the session for that.